# IBundleTransform implementation that runs on every request

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, scriptbundle

I'd like to implement a custom [IBundleTransform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.optimization.ibundletransform%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that is executed for every request. This would allow it to send user-specific CSS to each user.

However, it seems that even if I set the [UseServerCache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.optimization.bundlecontext.useservercache%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property to false, the transform only runs on the first request.

Is is possible to execute the transform on every request?

Comment: How does the URL look like?

Comment: It has the usual ?v=xxxxx querystring.

Comment: It likely be more efficient to just include an extra custom style sheet per user rather than run bundling and minification on every request.